# Select records after specific date in SQL

Tags: sql, aqua-data-studio

I have a column in my database called "begin_date".
I am trying to select records where the begin_date are greater than a specific date. I put

```
select * from Table_Name
where begin_date >= '1/1/2014'
```

However, it returns error message "String to date conversion error".
I am not sure how to modify the query to make it work? 
Thanks!

Comment: try changing the date format `..begin_date >= '2014-01-01'`

Comment: Yay, it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try using ISO (8601) standard date formats:

```
select *
from Table_Name
where begin_date >= '2014-01-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from table
where data >= '01/01/2014'
```